# Сортировка данных из одного столбца в несколько на MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Есть таблица в базе данных, в которой данные представлены в следующем виде:

```
| id | attribute | value |
| 69 | Capacity  | 1.6 l |
| 69 | Power     | 99 PS |
```

Как можно вывести данные из такой таблицы в приведённом ниже виде?

```
| id | Capacity | Power |
| 69 | 1.6 l    | 99 PS |
```

Написал, что-то подобное, но там NULL через раз вылетает.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    CASE attribute WHEN 'Capacity' THEN value END AS capacity,
    CASE attribute WHEN 'Power' THEN value END AS powerr,
FROM passanger_car_attributes
WHERE id = 69
```

Comment: Обычный PIVOT. Если список финальных полей фиксирован - условное агрегирование. Иначе хранимая процедура с динамическим SQL.

Comment: *Написал, что-то подобное, но там NULL через раз вылетает.* Добавить GROUP BY (lkz одного id не требуется) и MAX().

Answer (score 0):

Помог Akina из комментариев, на что ему большое спасибо. Действительно PIVOT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    id,
    MAX(CASE attribute WHEN 'Capacity' THEN value END) AS capacity,
    MAX(CASE attribute WHEN 'Power' THEN value END) AS powerr,
FROM passanger_car_attributes
WHERE id = 69
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: А DISTINCT-то тут зачем?